# Chemical elements or compounds with yellowish white color

Tags: color, elements, elemental-analysis

Are there chemical elements or compounds that have a yellowish white (cream) color in their natural state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Aluminium(III) chloride - often described as white but samples is sometimes contaminated with iron(III) chloride giving it a light yellow color
2. Antimony(V) oxide - pale yellow solid
3. Bismuth(III) oxide - light yellow solid
4. Rhodium(III) oxide - lemon yellow
5. Cerium(IV) oxide - pale yellow-white compound
6. Dysprosium(III) nitrate - white to pale yellow
7. Holmium(III) oxide- Color depends on lighting condition. In daylight, it is tannish light yellow; Under trichromatic light, it is fiery orange red (Thanks @EdV)
8. Samarium(III) oxide - light yellow
9. Silver(I) iodide - samples can have a range of color(white to pale yellow to yellow) due to impurity and photosensitization
10. Selenium(IV) chloride - white to faint yellow volatile solid
11. Gold(III) chloride - pale yellow to yellow
12. Potassium Telluride - pale yellow
13. Thallium(III) bromide - pale yellow
14. Some vanadate salts are light yellow

Bromium nitrate is pale yellow but not confirmed. [Silver(I) bromide and lead(II) bromide are light yellow and white cream colored respectively.](https://www.chemistryscl.com/chemistry_theories/precipitate/main.html)

Above data source: http://lanthanumkchemistry.over-blog.com/article-the-colors-of-chemicals-complexes-104821449.html

Comment: (+1) Excellent list! I have numbers 5, 8 and 11 and can confirm that the color of holmium (III) oxide depends on the illumination, as per [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmium%28III%29_oxide).

Comment: @EdV Thank you. I am editing that information onto the answer. I was hoping for someone to confirm the list as I compiled the data from a single source.

Comment: In addition to the various inorganic compounds listed above, there are countless organic compounds (and mixtures/emulsions/suspensions/etc. of organic compounds) that satisfy this criterion. Also, sulfur contamination of something that's normally white will give you something yellow.

Answer (score 5):

[Calcium hypochlorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hypochlorite#:%7E:text=Calcium%20hypochlorite%20is%20an%20inorganic,and%20as%20a%20bleaching%20agent.) is an example of such a yellowish white compound.

Another example would be [Silver Bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bromide)

Comment: I am unable to comment and so this is the only way I can answer a question

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the reason for downvoting?

Comment: The only reason I can think is that your link to Ca(OCl)2 takes you to AgBr

Comment: Thanks for that. @IanBush I had both links marked in the answer but had a mix up in alloting them. I fixed the issue.

Comment: Article you link says calcium hypochlorite is white/gray. Also such questions are supposed to be closed as too broad, not answered.

Answer (score 4):

The reaction of any acid on a thiosulfate solution makes a precipitate of sulfur $\ce{S_8}$ which is pale yellow, nearly white.

Answer (score 2):

Undyed ("natural") nylon is yellowish-white:

[image]

Source of picture: aiplastics.com